# Create Grouped UITableview in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin

How I can create grouped in UI Table View. Check image I want to implement same in xamarin.iOS.

[image]

Comment: If you have implented it, please add your full code with answer.. I'm having problem in implemeting, It would be very good of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to create a TableSource  -Class which is holding your data and sets the headers for the sections (they are called sections in iOS).

You need to override following methods:

```
    public override string TitleForHeader(UITableView tableView, nint section)
    {
        return SessionGroups == null ? string.Empty : SessionGroups[(int)section].Key;
    }

    public override nint NumberOfSections(UITableView tableView)
    {
        return SessionGroups == null ? 0 : SessionGroups.Count;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return SessionGroups == null ? 0 : SessionGroups[(int)section].Count;
    }

    public override string[] SectionIndexTitles(UITableView tableView)
    {
        return SessionGroups == null ? new string[0] : SessionGroups.Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
    }
```

You can find more infos [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/part_2_-_populating_a_table_with_data/). In the 'Adding an Index' and 'Adding Headers and Footers' section.

**Edit**

Important is also the datasource structure. You Need something like a keyedlist (or a dictionary with a list like showed in the above link).

```
protected IList<ObservableKeyedList<string, string>> SessionGroups;

// Just override the ItemsSource property (base class we use: MvxStandardTableViewSource)
public new IList<ObservableKeyedList<string, string>> ItemsSource
{
    get { return SessionGroups; }
    set
    {
        SessionGroups = value;
        ReloadTableData();
    }
}
```

The first string of the `ObservableKeyedList` is the key for your section/group. And the second string is the value you want to show on the UI: The second can also be a model with different properties.

So you just Need to order/group your data in the above structure and set the ItemsSource of your UiTableSource.. thats it =)

Heres the ObservableKeyedList we use:

```
public class ObservableKeyedList<TKey, TItem> : ObservableCollection<TItem>
    {
        public TKey Key { protected set; get; }

        public ObservableKeyedList(TKey key, IEnumerable<TItem> items) : base(items)
        {
            Key = key;
        }

        public ObservableKeyedList(IGrouping<TKey, TItem> grouping) : base(grouping)
        {
            Key = grouping.Key;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks joehi. I got your point. But How I can group base on days? I have one DataSet there is one column of day. I want to group this.

Comment: I updated my answer with additional infos. Maybe that could show you the direction you can go

Comment: Why unable to add reference of ObservableKeyedList? If I used KeyedCollection then SessionGroups[(int)section].Key not working. :(

Comment: `ObservableKeyedList` is a custom cluss I created. The source is in my answer. Just add this class to your solution and it sould work.

Comment: Thank you so much. Kindly, also share controller side code. I'm litle bit confuse. 
before I'm using: List<TableItem> tableItems = new List<TableItem>();
then fill this list tblCourse.Source = new CourseDetailTableSource(this, tableItems);

Comment: The table just Needs a DataSource which has a Key in it. My `ObservableKeyedList` ist just one solution. Only a List with items will not work, as far as I know.